# Установка времени в форме

Tags: дата, html, javascript, время

Здравствуйте.

Нужно чтобы была возможность установить время и с возможностью установить шаг прокрутки 5 минут, но не с помощью type="time"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[jquery-timepicker](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-timepicker/)